Android studio project "SSL peer shut down incorrectly"
I created a new android studio project, and the error "SSL peer shut down incorrectly" occured.
enter image description here
I have tried these ways to address it, but all of them didn't work:

go to android SDK and check force https://.. sources to be fetched using http://
go to gradle>wrapper>gradle-wradle-wrapper.propersities and change distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip to distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip (after I did that, the build shows
Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-bin.zip'. The cached zip file C:\Users\suiwo.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-8.0-bin\4qlezyew53f1vxa733vpgk9hf\gradle-8.0-bin.zip may be corrupted. Delete file and sync project
)
close the firewall
use a vpn and go to file>settings>apperance&behaviors>system settings>http proxy, and then check auto-detect proxy settings and manual proxy configuration separately(When I click the check connection button and input https://google.com to test connection, it shows connection successful)
restart android studio
reboot my computer
change to another network or select another vpn node

I nearly tried all the solutions I can find on the internet, but all of them didn't work.
btw, previously, I used pip and npm with vpn and also encountered a similar problem. When I opened vpn, both npm and pip didn't work. After I wrote the proxy into their configuration files, they worked.
So I guess whether it's caused by incorrect system network settings?
I have been tortured by this problem for a few days, I really feel frustrated about that.
So if anyone can help me resolve it, I would greatly appreciate it!

The problem was resolved after I changed my vpn app to Clash, and changed the port at 'http proxy' in android studio to Clash's port. Sync again, it works.
